# Print as XML file when using cURL

Tags: php, curl

How can I display the data returned from cURL as an XML document on the page?

Currently I get something like this:

```
[something] => 189129
[somethingElse] => exampleContent
[somethingElse1] => someMoreExamples
[somethingElse2] => evenMoreExamples
```

From this code:

```
$url = "http://example/";

$header[] = 'Accept: application/xml';
$header[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xmlResponse = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
?>

<?php
print_r('<pre>');
print_r($xmlResponse);
print_r('</pre>');
?>
```

Is there a way to format the response directly as XML or a way to transform it after with php?

Thanks.

Comment: You want curl to reformat your data to xml? Are you using curl directly or via php, perl etc?

Comment: I am using cURL via PHP and I want it to be printed on the page like an xml document.

Comment: Then tag the question with PHP (so it will be seen) and add some php code (so we can help)

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the suggestions. I have added some example code to the post and changed the tag to Php.

Comment: No worries @Bogdan - welcome to StackOverflow, people are usually friendly and helpful here as long as the question is asked well. I've undone the downvote someone gave you.

Comment: Note: `print_r` is *only* meant for debugging purposes, *not* for printing strings normally.  You want to be using `echo` instead.

Comment: Why not just `echo $response;`?  Do you need to re-format the data in anyway first?  Why not just echo it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

If the data you are fetching is already xml, all you need to do is

```
echo htmlentities($xmlResponse);
```

---

**Previous answer (for posterity):**

I believe you can do something like:

```
// start your xml with a simple doctype
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?><data/>');

// loop through each array entry, adding the key/value as a child to 'data'
foreach($response AS $key=>$value)
{
    $xml->addChild($key, $value);
}
// get the xml
$xmlResponse = $xml->asXML();

// output it, encoding the html characters so it displays ok
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlentities($xmlResponse);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam. I will upvote your answer as soon as I get some reputations.